Ways of reading changes in application.properties file while the application is still running
I currently have a springboot application in which I have defined a few custom properties in the application properties file, while I am running the application, I want a feature in which I modify the application properties file, save it, commit and push it on to GitLab, once I do this, I want the locally running app which was never terminated to pick up changes from the commit and modify according to how the changes were made in the properties file. Are there any ways to do this?
I tried using /actuator/refresh, but it returns an empty array and I am stuck currently, it does not pull the most recent changes onto the running application.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Probably you can use the Github REST API to poll the file for changes: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents
